# How to divide two columns using Pipes and . (dot) references

Tags: r

Problem: I have a set of dataframes with numerical columns with different column names. The columns are in the same position each time. The df `MatA` has columns named `iBAQ.MatA.01` to `30`, when data frame `YoungA` has columns named `iBAQ.YoungA.01` to `30`. I want to divide column 11 by column 8. They are always in the same position, so `MatA[9]` is equivalent to `YoungA[9]`.

I am using `dplyr` to pipe a bunch of commands and would be happy if I would not have to manually edit a lot of lines with updated variable names. That's why I want to use `.` to reference the original data frame. 
However, this results in a wrong output where a lot of identical columns are created as shown in the minimal example below:

```
> library(dplyr)
> Data <- data.frame(
    X = sample(1:10),
    Y = sample(1:10)
)


> Data2 <- Data %>%
    mutate(ratio = X/Y)

> Data3 <- Data %>%
    mutate(ratio = Data$X/Data$Y)

> Data2, Data3
    X  Y     ratio
1   8  1 8.0000000
2   1  6 0.1666667
3   5 10 0.5000000
4   3  8 0.3750000
5   2  3 0.6666667
6  10  4 2.5000000
7   6  9 0.6666667
8   7  5 1.4000000
9   9  7 1.2857143
10  4  2 2.0000000
```

The output is what I want, however this approach required manual adaptation of each variable name for each new dataframe.

Trying different way of dividing but referencing the column by position, not ID works only when not used in a `mutate` function.

```
> Data[1]/Data[2]

           X
1  8.0000000
2  0.1666667
3  0.5000000
4  0.3750000
5  0.6666667
6  2.5000000
7  0.6666667
8  1.4000000
9  1.2857143
10 2.0000000

> Data4 <- Data %>%
    mutate(ratio = Data[1]/Data[2])

> Data5 <- Data %>%
    mutate(ratio = .[1] / . [2])

> Data4, Data5
    X  Y    ratio.    ratio.    ratio.    ratio.    ratio.    ratio.    ratio.    ratio.    ratio.    ratio.
1   8  1 8.0000000 8.0000000 8.0000000 8.0000000 8.0000000 8.0000000 8.0000000 8.0000000 8.0000000 8.0000000
2   1  6 0.1666667 0.1666667 0.1666667 0.1666667 0.1666667 0.1666667 0.1666667 0.1666667 0.1666667 0.1666667
3   5 10 0.5000000 0.5000000 0.5000000 0.5000000 0.5000000 0.5000000 0.5000000 0.5000000 0.5000000 0.5000000
4   3  8 0.3750000 0.3750000 0.3750000 0.3750000 0.3750000 0.3750000 0.3750000 0.3750000 0.3750000 0.3750000
5   2  3 0.6666667 0.6666667 0.6666667 0.6666667 0.6666667 0.6666667 0.6666667 0.6666667 0.6666667 0.6666667
6  10  4 2.5000000 2.5000000 2.5000000 2.5000000 2.5000000 2.5000000 2.5000000 2.5000000 2.5000000 2.5000000
7   6  9 0.6666667 0.6666667 0.6666667 0.6666667 0.6666667 0.6666667 0.6666667 0.6666667 0.6666667 0.6666667
8   7  5 1.4000000 1.4000000 1.4000000 1.4000000 1.4000000 1.4000000 1.4000000 1.4000000 1.4000000 1.4000000
9   9  7 1.2857143 1.2857143 1.2857143 1.2857143 1.2857143 1.2857143 1.2857143 1.2857143 1.2857143 1.2857143
10  4  2 2.0000000 2.0000000 2.0000000 2.0000000 2.0000000 2.0000000 2.0000000 2.0000000 2.0000000 2.0000000
```

My goal is to end with a nomenclature like for Data5, as this is the most easily adapted for several different dataframes with identical layout but different variable and dataframe names. I'd also be happy about any idea how to express this simple division differently so it doesn't break.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that this works:

```
Data6 <- Data %>%
    mutate(ratio = .[,1] / .[,2])
```

Apparently referencing a column outside of a piped argument works differently than inside.

I am not deleting this as a reference for others.

Comment: You should review this chapter on [Subsetting in R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html).  The single bracket returns a one-column data.frame, hence the evaluation error when using pipes.  If you don't like the extra commas in your workaround, you can always use double brackets instead to access columns:  `Data %>% mutate(Ratio = .[[1]]/.[[2]])`

Comment: Thank you, that is very valuable input.